# Python - Converting dollar values to float

Tags: python, string, pandas, floating-point

I have sales data that is stored as a string.  i'm trying to convert to a float so that I can aggregate the data but I'm receiving the following error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'revenue'.

I also tried to replace the dollar signs and commas but the type is still string.

```
>>> df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].replace('$| ','')
>>> type('revenue')
<class 'str'>
```

I also tried the following

```
pd.to_numeric(df.revenue)
```

But this also gave me an error that said "ValueError: Unable to parse string "$1,557.97 "

The data also has brackets around negative numbers (ie (45.22)) that i'm not sure how to convert.

Comment: `.to_dtype(float)` ?

Comment: `type('revenue')` checks string `'revenue'` not column `df['revenue']` - check `df.dtypes`

Comment: but if i replace $ in the df['revenue'] should it not convert the data within the column?

Comment: It convert automatically only when you read from file. In other moments you have to do it manually.

Comment: how do i do it manually?

Comment: manually - you have to use `pd.to_numeric()` - but string need to have only numbers and `.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `regex=True` and `\$` because `$` has special meaning in `regex`.
You have to also remove `,`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'revenue': ["$1,557.97 "]})

df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].replace('\$|,', '', regex=True)

df['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['revenue'])

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

You don't have to remove spaces if they are at the beginning or at the end - but spaces can't be between digits.

---

Instead of `pd.to_numeric()` you can also use

```
df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].astype(float)
```

but you still have to remove `$` and `,` before converting to `float`

---

**EDIT:** To remove `(( ))` you may use `regex`

```
.replace('\$|,|\(|\)', '', regex=True)
```

Because `(` `)` have special meaning in `regex` so you have to use `\(`, `\)`

You can also use `regex` `[...]` which will no need \

```
.replace('[$,()]', '', regex=True)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'revenue': [" $1,557.97 ", "((45.22))"]})

#df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].replace('\$|,|\(|\)', '', regex=True)
df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].replace('[$,()]', '', regex=True)

#df['revenue'] = pd.to_numeric(df['revenue'])
df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].astype(float)

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Is the "\" infront of the "$" needed if regex is True? Is it possible to do this with regex=False?

Comment: Yes, you'd do something like `.replace('$','').replace(',','')`. Can't do it in a single call without `regex=True`.

Comment: if you use `|` to replace different chars then you need `regex=True` because `|` works only in `regex`. If you use `regex` then `$` means `"beginning of line"`, not dollar. To use dollar in `regex` you need `\$` . Without `regex` you have to replace every char separatelly - like in @nneonneo comment.

Comment: Thanks. I did it the long way but it works. Will provide my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Furas.  I did it as follows using your code as guidance.

```
df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].replace('\$|,','', regex=True).replace('\(','-', regex=True).replace('\)','', regex=True)
pd.to_numeric(df['revenue'])
```